# JavaScript Smooth Scroll Explained

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, smooth-scrolling

I have seen the following code snippet on a number of pages. I understand that it is used for smooth scrolling according to different id anchor tags. However, I am still  a little confused about what/how the regex replacement, `this`, and `hash` variables work.

What exactly is this frequent code snippet doing?

```
$(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the code, `this` refers to the link clicked. `this.hash` refers to `hash` of the link.

Here's further breakdown of the code:

```
$(function() {

    // Binding an event handler to all anchors that contain
    // a hash (#), but not necessarily JUST a hash - like href="#"
    // which is typically used in JS...

    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

        // Two conditional checks
        // First:
        // location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
        // What we're doing is replacing the first forward slash (/) in the pathname
        // for the current location and comparing it to the link that's been clicked.
        // So http://personalsite.com/test/link/src, which normally would have
        // a pathname of /test/link/src would be test/link/src

        // The or check (||) is to see if the link matches the current domain
        // location.hostname == this.hostname

        // Basically, we want an internal anchor for the page we're on.

        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            // Assigning the variable target, with the hash of the link that's been clicked
            // which is conveniently enough, a jquery selector for IDs (i.e. #hash)
            var target = $(this.hash);

            // We check the target length - basically, does the element exist?
            // If length equals to 0, we query the DOM by name attribute. Otherwise, we just re-assign target to self.
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');

            // The rest is self explanatory... (animation  using the target's offset)
            // The return false prevents default behavior

            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi @Elric, I didn't write the code, but I did verify it still works in 2017.

Comment: Thanks @Jack , I found out that height:100% on css of body or html blocks the animate script. You need to use min-height: 100% ; height: auto; :O